# R cannot change line type in a plot

Tags: r, plot

I have a data frame like this:

```
   Var1   Var2 Freq
1  1970 sigmod   28
2  1971 sigmod   21
3  1972 sigmod   21
4  1974 sigmod   36
5  1975 sigmod   46
6  1976 sigmod   21
7  1977 sigmod   32
8  1978 sigmod   45
9  1979 sigmod   24
10 1980 sigmod  102
...
```

When I plotted a graph, I received this:

[image]

I tried these code, but there are no changes in the plot:

```
plot(tab$Var1, tab$Freq, type="b")
plot(tab$Var1, tab$Freq, type="b", lty=2, pch=17)
```

Please tell me the reason, and how to fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as if you have created `tab` by using `as.data.frame(table(...)))` or `data.frame(table(...))`.

`as.data.frame.table` and `data.frame(table(...))` will coerce dimnames to `factor`.

```
# an example
foo <- data.frame(a = sample(10,size=100,replace=TRUE),b = sample(10, size = 50, replace = TRUE))

str(data.frame(table(foo))
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a   : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ b   : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Freq: int  1 2 2 2 3 0 4 0 0 0 ..

str(as.data.frame(table(foo))
# 'data.frame': 100 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a   : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  $ b   : Factor w/ 10 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Freq: int  1 2 2 2 3 0 4 0 0 0 ..
```

You could use `reshape2` to create the frequency table  table, this will preserve the types of the variables

```
library(reshape2)
str(dcast(a+b~'Freq',data = foo,value.var = 'b', fun = length))
# 'data.frame': 56 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 ...
#  $ b   : int  1 2 3 5 6 7 8 10 1 2 ...
#  $ Freq: int  1 1 2 4 2 2 1 2 2 5 ...
```

or use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(foo)
 str(DT[, .N, by = list(a,b)])
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    56 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ a: int  1 4 5 10 2 1 5 4 4 7 ...
#  $ b: int  5 6 1 3 2 6 4 4 5 1 ...
#  $ N: int  4 1 3 1 5 2 3 3 1 4 ...
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: yes, I created tab by using `tab <- data.frame(table(sigmod$YEAR, sigmod$conf))`, but I haven't understood your solution yet :(

Comment: @LNgocTu -- your plot looks odd because "Var1" and "Var2" are factor variables (whereas 'YEAR' should be numeric for your desired plot to work)

Comment: ok, I used this `year = as.numeric(as.character(tab$Var1))` and problem was solved. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions above are on the right tract, Freq is a factor but you want it as a numeric.

Try this:

```
freq=as.numeric(tab$Freq);head(freq)
## if the above does not work properly (show the exact same values); this should
freq=as.numeric(as.character(tab$Freq));head(freq)
plot(tab$Var1, freq, type="b", lty=2, pch=17)
```

Let us know if this does not work (along which how does freq and the plot look).

Comment: I tried as you said, but the plot didn't change as I want. And I think Freq is not a factor because I entered the code `> str(tab)` and received the result 
`'data.frame': 43 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Var1: Factor w/ 43 levels "1970","1971",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Var2: Factor w/ 1 level "sigmod": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Freq: int  28 21 21 36 46 21 32 45 24 102 ...`
Var1 and Var2 are factors

Comment: we should do with Var1, as `year = as.numeric(as.character(tab$Var1))` and then plot(year, tab$Freq, type="b"). It worked. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. I used this:
`year = as.numeric(as.character(tab$Var1))`
and then plot the graph:
`plot(year, tab$Freq, type="b")`
Thank @mnel and @Sahil Seth for your answers.
(Sorry, I have to wait for 8 hours to inform the answer ^^)